# Openid Connect signing in through multiple providers

Tags: authentication, authorization, openid

If i sign on to multiple OpenId providers (such as AOL and Google), will the authentication profile be unified between the multiple providers or will there be different profiles?

Comment: note that your topic title says OpenID Connect but AOL does not support OpenID Connect yet and is still on OpenID 2.0

Comment: Ah thanks I guess I got a bit confused whether AOL used Connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That totally depends on what you're signing in to. Both options are feasible and the Relying Party that uses AOL/Google for login decides how the accounts are treated/connected.

Comment: So if I understand properly, if one wanted to use connect multiple Identity providers, the Relying Party would have associate both of the Identity Tokens returned.  And the Identity provider has no knowledge of other Identity Providers?

Comment: Indeed, the identity provider has no knowledge of the other identity providers that the RP may connect to and whose identity tokens may be associated with user accounts at the RP.